# How do you call a function of a module in Python if the module should be called with a list or variable?

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, module

I have a module, in the module is a subcomponent which contains a multitude of functions. I need to iterate through a list of names which contains the names of the modules and call the functions. this does not work, "because module has no attribute list". How do I make list[x] callable as a subcomponent of module instead of "list" the name.

file 1:

```
def x():
   print('x')

def y():
   print('y')

def z():
   print('z')
```

file 2:

```
import module # containing functions x(),y(),z()
list = ['x','y','z']
for x in list:
   module.list[x]()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```py
import module

lst = ["x", "y", "z"]

for item in lst:
    getattr(module, item)()
```

Prints:

```
<function x at 0x7f2c56129e50>
<function y at 0x7f2c56129f70>
<function z at 0x7f2c560e4c10>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getattr` to access to the "content" of the module.

Using [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#dir) to "introspect" the content of the module:

```
import my_module

func_names = ['x','y','z']
callable_funcs = []

for stuffs in dir(my_module):
    if stuff in func_names:
        callable_funcs.append(getattr(my_module, stuff))

# make a dictionary
funcs = dict(zip(func_names, callable_funcs))

# usage
x = funcs['x']
print(x())
```

---

Another way using `getattr` and `hasattr`:

```
import my_module

func_names = ['x','y','z']
callable_funcs = []

for f_name in func_names:
    if hasattr(my_module, f_name):
        callable_funcs.append(getattr(my_module, f_name))

# make a dictionary
funcs = dict(zip(func_names, callable_funcs))

# usage
x = funcs['x']
print(x())
```

It can be done also using a dictionary comprehension:

```
import my_module

func_names = ['x','y','z']

funcs = {f_name: getattr(my_module, f_name) for f_name in func_names if hasattr(my_module, f_name)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just store the *functions* in the list?

```
>>> def x():
...     print("x")
... 
>>> def y():
...     print("y")
... 
>>> functions = [x, y]
>>> for f in functions:
...     f()
... 
x
y
>>>
```

Comment: They are in a different file, the names are being read in a for loop with getmembers() if is function(). You can't call what I describe because the list in module.list is not iterable. the values need to be attached to a button that triggers the function. it simply does not work the way you describe, and your description is way more simplistic then what I am trying to achieve.